# Apache Commons FileUpload only save a part of the file

Tags: apache-commons-fileupload, gwtupload

I'm using a gwt widget gwtupload.client.Uploader, and i'm trying to save the file into a blob column in a database using fileupload streaming api.
The problem is that if the file is bigger than 3k only saves 3k (well 3.25K). 
Thanks for the help.
Here is the code:

```
try {
    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
    upload.setProgressListener(listener);
    FileItemIterator iter = upload.getItemIterator(request);
    InputStream stream = null;
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        FileItemStream item = iter.next();
        String name = item.getFieldName();
        stream = item.openStream();
        Object o = getThreadLocalRequest().getSession().getAttribute(PortailServiceIMPL.FICHIER_SESSION_STORE_KEY);
        if (o != null && o instanceof Fichier) {
            uploadService.sauvegarder((Fichier) o, stream);
            listener.update(listener.getContentLength(),
                    listener.getContentLength(), 0);
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                    "Impossible de recuperer le fichier de la session.");
        }
    }
    if (stream != null) {
        stream.close();
    }
} catch (SizeLimitExceededException e) {
    RuntimeException ex = new UploadSizeLimitException(
            e.getPermittedSize(), e.getActualSize());
    listener.setException(ex);
    throw ex;
} catch (UploadSizeLimitException e) {
    listener.setException(e);
    throw e;
} catch (UploadCanceledException e) {
    listener.setException(e);
    throw e;
} catch (UploadTimeoutException e) {
    listener.setException(e);
    throw e;
} catch (Exception e) {
    logger.error("UPLOAD-SERVLET (" + request.getSession().getId()
            + ") Unexpected Exception -> " + e.getMessage() + "\n"
            + stackTraceToString(e));
    e.printStackTrace();
    RuntimeException ex = new UploadException(e);
    listener.setException(ex);
    throw ex;
}
```

The lina that saves the file is :

```
uploadService.sauvegarder((Fichier) o, stream);
```

And there are like 4 methods after until reach the the code to save the InputStream (the InputStream is not touched):

```
public void storeBlob(long id, InputStream pInputStream) throws Exception {
    try {

        java.sql.Connection conn = //get the connection;

        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(SQL_STORE);

        ps.setBinaryStream(1, pInputStream, pInputStream.available());
        ps.setLong(2, id);

        ps.executeUpdate();

        ps.close();

        em.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        em.getTransaction().rollback();
        throw new Exception(t);
    }

}
```

If I use the FileItemFactory it worked, but that's not what I want:

```
FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
List<FileItem> uploadedItems = upload.parseRequest(request);
    for (FileItem item : uploadedItems) {
        InputStream stream = item.getInputStream();
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some work around, I solved it.

in the storeBlob method i can't use the pInputStream.available(). So, this is the line i used:

```
ps.setBinaryStream(1, pInputStream);
```